# how to Detect a KeyCode event of a function key?

Tags: arduino, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I am trying to mimic the "mute mic" and "turn camera off" keys that are on my laptop's keyboard [Lenovo Yoga 920, if it matters] function row in order to create some physical buttons for them (with either arduino or AutoHotKeys for example).

[image]

I was able to get the key code of most other keys whether by using local scripts on my PC or even online websites like https://keycode.info/
Those scripts and sites finds every other key codes but those I wanted.

How can I copy those commands and use them from somewhere else but the laptop's keyboard?

Closest thing I could find is this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125476/figure-out-the-emitted-keycode-for-fnf6
but it relates to Linux only.

Thanks!

Comment: Your computer's "Disable Mic" and "Disable Webcam" buttons are likely not like other keys that have keycodes, such as "Change Volume". Unlike the latter, Windows won't be able to see that you have pressed those Disable Keys, since those are largely handled by your computer itself. Most software-side solutions likely wont be able to trigger your computer's hardware functions like that. You might have some better luck asking on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: thanks.
@Spyre can you think of any way to mimic their action?

Comment: My best idea would be to use an Arduino to physically press the button on your keyboard. Of course, this is inefficient, impractical, and just dumb in general. StackOverflow is a place where you can get programming and code-related questions. As a mentioned, I feel like this is a problem that the people at SuperUser are better at solving, since this is now more of a hardware question. [Differences between StackOverflow and SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: Some special keys can be detected using Key history in any active ahk script to get 3-digit hexadecimal value. For detailed instructions try this: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Arduino Leonardo, this can easily be done using NicoHood HID-Project. Install the library by going to `Manage Libraries` and searching for `HID-Project` from NicoHood. Under `Examples->HID_Project->Consumer`, you can find examples of how to send the special media keys.

https://github.com/NicoHood/HID/wiki/Consumer-API

If all you have is something like an Arduino UNO or other device without a full HID-compliant USB interface, you will need to flash his bootloader onto the device. Instructions are below.

https://github.com/NicoHood/HoodLoader2

Finally, if you are on Windows and looking for a solution that uses AutoHotKeys or Python or another scripting language, below are the key codes that you are looking for. For example, mute is `VK_VOLUME_MUTE - 0xAD`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: I don't quite think this is the solution OP was looking for. Based on what I understood, his computer had special "Disable Camera" and "Disable Microphone" keys, do not fall into the category of standard media keys that can be accessed with standard [Media Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#multimedia). Just to note, muting the microphone is different than "Disabling" it. When the mic is disabled, its like you unplugged a USB mic from the device; the computer no longer recognizes the microphone on the system (at least from my experiences).

Comment: Answer is not applicable as ^^ noted ^^ and the point should be emphasized that laptops in particular have special keys that are *not* handled by the HID spec.  

Mine (a Sager) also has a key to toggle three levels of keyboard backlighting and it drives me crazy that when the machine boots up it defaults to low and I can not turn it off without physically pressing the key combo twice!  Ugh!